# SQL Server - append text field with rotation

Tags: sql-server, append, log-rotation

Let's say I have `nvarchar(300)` column.

I append the text as follows:

```
update tablename set fieldname = fieldname + 'appended string'
```

How can I tell SQL Server to automatically trim the text from beginning to ensure it never exceeds the maximum column length?

Comment: If you're dealing with **Unicode** string literals in SQL Server (and `nvarchar` is Unicode) - you should always use the `N'...'` notation - e.g. `update tablename set fieldname = fieldname + N'appended string'` to make it clear that your string literal is Unicode ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) function for that:

```
update tablename set fieldname = RIGHT(fieldname + N'appended string', 300)
```

Comment: @LoveDotNet I think it really trims from the beginning and your example shows just that.

Comment: Then why it ends with "stringappended string"? Shouldn't it always end with "stringappended"?

Comment: @LoveDotNet if it only trims from the beginning, then the end should be left untouched and it should be `"appended string"`

Comment: @LoveDotNet imagine you had concatenated the string three times: `"appended stringappended stringappended string"`. Now if you trimmed 9 chars from the beginning, how would it look?